# Add a link to tasklist navigation bar in Camunda

Tags: camunda

I'd like to add a button that opens a link in the tasklist navigation bar:

[image: Camunda tasklist navbar]

I read the [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/webapps/tasklist/tasklist-plugins/) and it's clear that I have to add a plugin to the tasklist app but I can't figure out how to do it based on the given example.

Any hints, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Camunda docs very un-helpful. Consequently, I decided to find existing plugins to better understand what is needed. Luckily, I stumbled upon a sample project called [tasklist-plugin-easy-search](https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/tasklist-plugin-easy-search).
I cloned this project and used it as a base.

Within your newly cloned project , make sure that the class name in

```
 /code-master/snippets/tasklist-plugin-easy-search/src/main/java/com/camunda/demo/plugin/tasklist/search/easy/EasySearchPlugin
```

is referenced in a file called org.camunda.bpm.tasklist.plugin.spi.TasklistPlugin that resides in the directory

```
META-INF/services.
```

There are a limited number of locations on the Tasklist webpage whereby you can place your plugin.

Please have a look [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/webapps/tasklist/tasklist-plugins/#plugin-points).

Once selected you can change the code in /code-master/snippets/tasklist-plugin-easy-search/src/main/resources/plugin-webapp/easy-search-plugin/app/plugin.js

```
var Configuration = ['ViewsProvider', function (ViewsProvider) {

ViewsProvider.registerDefaultView('tasklist.navbar.action', {
    id: 'claim-interface-plugin',
    label: 'Search',
    url: 'plugin://claim-interface-plugin/static/app/claim-interface-plugin.html',
    controller: Controller,
    priority: 1000
});
```

}];

Finally, to integrate this plugin into you Camunda web app, you should create a Jar file. Next, shut down your Camunda web app if it is running.
Thereafter, go into your Camunda web app directory and place the Jar in

```
/server/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/camunda/WEB-INF/lib/.
```

Start up your Camunda web app.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your help! I also think that the documentation is far from perfect. It's a great product, but quite difficult to customize only by following their guides. I had to use an alternate solution for the navbar button but I'll follow your steps to see if I manage to add it. I'll update the post with the results, cheers!

Comment: @Fel Pleasure man, yeah let me know if you get stuck. Also note that I found version 7.13 the most stable so far, so try with that one. I also wrote a blog on it here:https://smartstack.medium.com/camunda-tasklist-plugin-7f51628015cb

Comment: Hi! I followed the steps you suggested and it works perfectly. Now I have the 2 buttons that I needed, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Fel Pleasure broo